# Why AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges don't works

Tags: cocoa, authorization, root

Why does the command "AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges" works fine with some command like "/bin/mv" and does not work with another kind of "/usr/sbin/calendarserver_manage_principals"...
Thanks

Comment: In what specific way does it not work? What error is returned? What, if anything, is logged to the console? Also, I have no such thing as `/usr/sbin/calendarserver_manage_principals` on my system.

Comment: This command is only on Lion Server, Insufficient permissions for server... Thanks

Comment: is it possible that command works with the uid number ? because NSLog(@"uid: %d", getuid()); return 501

Comment: It's possible. It sounds like `calendarserver_manage_principals` itself is being run just fine but then is refusing to operate because of some criteria it is imposing. I do know that `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()` results in real and effective UIDs that are different.

Comment: Why when setuid(0); seems not working, why ? the result is always 501

Comment: Where are you performing the `getuid()`? Are you launching a different program of your own?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the real user ID, you can invoke a trampoline program which just does `setuid(0)` and then uses an `exec` function to run `calendarserver_manage_principals`. You run that program with `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()`.